# Using tools.run_flow() raises SSLHandshake "certificate verify" error in Google Sheets API tutorial

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, windows-10, google-sheets-api, oauth2client

I'm am pretty much following the Google Sheets getting started (in Python) to a tee. I've gotten the program to work on my Mac laptop, but it is failing as I am trying to run it on Windows. So far, I've checked that we do not have the firewall enabled on the machine.

Below is the error that appears after clicking through the authentication prompts that pop up in the browser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Authenticate.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "Authenticate.py", line 43, in main
    tools.run_flow(flow, store)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\tools.py", line 243, in run_flow
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 2054, in step2_exchange
    http, self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\johnsnow\packages\test\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1044, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: Since it's working on the Mac and not on Windows. Can it be related to the path where your credentials.json/client_secret.json is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how it happened as I was working in a virtualenv, but there was a dependency issue in the version of httplib2 and oauth2. After an uninstall and then reinstall, there was an error that the two libraries were incompatible.

Doing `pip freeze` showed I had `httplib2==0.8` but oauth2client required `httplib2=>0.9`.

This was resolved by doing `pip install --upgrade httplib2`.